# HBase BulkImport Failed - Encountered unrecoverable error from region server

Tags: hbase

I am trying to do a bulk import to HBase using LoadIncrementalHFiles. I got a error on

"2013-12-11 20:42:12,256 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles (LoadIncrementalHFiles-0): Encountered unrecoverable error from region server
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=10, exceptions:"

The disk space of the node is 850 GB, but only 59 GB was used and I got this exception. Is there any max size allotted for HBase or is there any other cause for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from where are you running the code for bulk load, but looks like your code is not able to resolve the IP's of your region servers. If you are running the code from your local make sure you add the IP's of the region server in the host file. For windows you can add entries in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file and if linux add in /etc/hosts.